# How can I customize the way Kubuntu acts with my keyboard inputs?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, input

I successfully installed Kubuntu, and the system works perfectly.

But the way Kubuntu is acting with my keyboard inputs is annoying. When I press <kbd>caps lock</kbd>, the system is waiting for me to release the key to unable the caps lock (not to able caps lock). THat's make begin sentences like this.

Secondly, when I'm pressing multiple keys at the same time, the system freezes the input like 0.5 seconds. It's not a problem for typing, but for playing, pressing "move forward" and "running" key at the same time, it is. The problem does not occur when a key is already pressed and I press another one.

System's informations :

KDE Plasma Version : 5.18.4

KDE Frameworks Version : 5.68.0

Qt Version : 5.12.8

Kernel version : 5.4.0-26-generic

OS-Type : 64-bit

EDIT :
My keyboard also seems to have a latency problem (I used it on windows and it was working fine)

Another EDIT : The second problem seems to come from Minecraft. I found someone having the same issue here : https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/cprt8u/minecraft_keyboard_problem_on_ubuntu_19/ewrbnja/?context=8&depth=9.

Another EDIT xd : Here's also a guy having the problem : https://superuser.com/questions/1470978/minecraft-1-13-keyboard-issue-with-ubuntu

Comment: Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add your release number to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my problem got fixed with this : https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-122421 !
I downloaded the pre-compiled file, made for archlinux but it worked tho.
It was a Minecraft bug !
But the caps lock pb is still here.